# Is there a function $f : N\to N$ such that every $(k-1)$-connected graph with minimum degree at least $f(k)$ is at least $k$-connected?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I tried to solve the following problem:

Is there a function $f: N \to N$ such that every $(k -1)$-connected graph
with minimum degree, at least $f(k)$ is at least $k$-connected?

I have understood what k-connectivity means and also the meaning of the minimal degree. But I don't get to connect the two things. Does anyone have any tips on the solution for a function?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can learn mathjax very easily here. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979 Try to use it next time.

Comment: A $0$-connected (i..e, arbitary) graph can fail to be $1$-connected, no matter what we know about its minimal degree.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388974/find-a-graph-such-that-kappag-lambdag-deltag/3389232#3389232

Answer (score 3):

Fix $m$ and $n$ with $n\gg m$ and consider a "$K_m$ made of $K_n$'s", i.e., we have $m$ disjoint copies of  $K_n$'s, pick a vertex from each of these, and add edges between any two of the $m$ picked vertices.
The minimal  degree of this graph is $n$, but the connectivity is determined by $m$.

Comment: Thanks for reply! How do you conclude from this that there is no function?